# how to show the top 5 counted values in the array php

Tags: php, arrays

I have a task and I want to show the top 5 counted countries in the array using php. I got many countries from the server and push those countries name into the array. I perform the array_count_value to count the number of each country. Then I perform arsort to sort the count of occurence. Then I perform the array_slice to show the top five countries. the output must be like this.

```
singapore
india
thailand
malaysia
usa
```

here is my code below.

```
    <?php

$country = array("singapore","usa","india","thailand","china","singapore","usa","india","thailand","singapore","usa","india",
"singapore","usa","singapore","italy","finalnd","finland","finland","finland","finland","finland","finland");
$values = array_count_values($country);
    arsort($values);
    $topfive = array_slice(array_keys($values), 0,5,true);
    print_r($topfive);

?>
```

When I run the script, the output is shown below...

```
    Array
(
    [0] => finland
    [1] => singapore
    [2] => usa
    [3] => india
    [4] => thailand
)
```

My question is how to show the top 5 counted countries only in the output using php.
Can you please help me fix this problem.  thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`print_r($topfive);` will directly print the array, you need to print out by for loop

```
foreach ($topfive as $value) {
   echo $value."\n";
}
```